# Easiest way to grab filesize of remote file in PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl

I was thinking of doing a head request with cURL, was wondering if this is the way to go?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Since the file is remote, you're completely dependent on the value of the `Content-Length` header (unless you want to download the whole file). You'll want to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true)` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true)`.

Answer (score 64):

The best solution which follows the KISS principle

```
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers("http://example.com/file.ext", 1));
$filesize = $head['content-length'];
```

Comment: This command doesn't return a key 'content-length' for me, here is there array it returns:
`'connection' => string 'close' (length=5)
  'date' => string 'Tue, 03 Jun 2014 20:55:55 GMT' (length=29)
  'server' => string 'Microsoft-IIS/6.0' (length=17)
  'x-powered-by' => string 'ASP.NET' (length=7)
  'x-aspnet-version' => string '4.0.30319' (length=9)
  'cache-control' => string 'private' (length=7)
  'content-type' => string 'image/gif'`

Comment: Quick question, why does it need array_change_key_case?

Comment: RE: "This command doesn't return a key 'content-length' for me" - make sure to set the second param to a value greater than 0 to get the headers in a key/value format. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior The remote server which provides the file may not include the information in the headers. Unfortunately, this cannot be fixed by the client.

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing using curl to send a HEAD request is a nice possibility ; something like this would probably do :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
var_dump($size);
```

And will get you :

```
float 3438
```

This way, you are using a HEAD request, and not downloading the whole file -- still, you depend on the remote server send a correct Content-length header.

Another option you might think about would be to use [`filesize`](http://php.net/filesize)... But **this will fail** : the documentation states *(quoting)* :

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can
>   also be used with some URL wrappers.
>   Refer to [List of Supported
>   Protocols/Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for a listing
>   of which wrappers support stat()
>   family of functionality.

And, unfortunately, with [HTTP and HTTPS wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), `stat()` is not supported...

If you try, you'll get an error, like this :

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed 
    for http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png
```

Too bad :-(

Comment: A note: the float number of output is in Bytes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using a HEAD request and checking for `Content-Length` is the standard way to do it, but you can't rely on it in general, since the server might not support it. The `Content-Length` header is optional, and further the server might not even implement the HEAD method. If you know which server you're probing, then you can test if it works, but as a general solution it isn't bullet proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a bulletproof solution you can just do:

```
strlen(file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: This will work, but it will also download the file first. Presumably, he wants to know the size before fetching it over the network.