# Check image size in url

Tags: php, image, url, image-size

I found a nifty little php function to check whether a url is an image - is there also a way to determine whether that image is e.g. > 1mb?

SOLUTION FOUND:

I found a viable solution here: [php how to get web image size in kb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272663/php-how-to-get-web-image-size-in-kb)

Comment: Download it and check the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3894706/187954

```
<?php
$headers = get_headers('http://humus101.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Hummus-soup.jpg');
$size = null;
foreach($headers as $h){
    /** look for Content-Length, and stick it in $size **/
}
if ($size === null){ //we didn't get a Content-Length header
    /** Grab file to local disk and use filesize() to set $size **/
}

echo "image is $size bytes";
```

Comment: thank you! I suppose $size would then have a value of 1048576 if it is 1mb (i.e. 1024*1024)?

Comment: oh I just saw that $size is an array with height and width of the image, but not the size in bytes. does anyone know how get that?

Comment: @Dennis I noticed at about the same time :) Updated my answer with reference to another SO answer

Comment: thank you! I think I found an even cleaner solution. Please see question edit.

Comment: @Dennis yes that does look more straight-forward! Best of luck for your project ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to this post, I think it will answer your question.
[Easiest way to grab filesize of remote file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401131/easiest-way-to-grab-filesize-of-remote-file-in-php)

There are 2 approaches (that I am aware of). One is to use CURL and fetch only the headers (more efficient, less reliable), and `file_get_contents (more reliable, less efficient)`.

Using CURL you can get just the `CONTENT_LENGTH` header which is the file size. Then you can do simple math from there to see if it is over 1mb. The problem there is that the remote server may not support that feature.

By using `strlen(file_get_contents("YOUR URL"))` you can get the total byes in the file, but the script has to download the file first, which is a problem if it is a large image.

To check the file type you can use substr to check the file extension.

Something like this could work, but has its own problems

```
$ext = substr($URL, -3, 3);

if($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'gif') {
   //is image
}else{
   //not image
}
```

Comment: The approach from Michael is better than mine

Comment: thank you! I think I found an even cleaner solution. Please see question edit.