# PHP filesize() don't work

Tags: php

I want use of `filesize` in php but if don't work for me. what do i do?

```
$img = 'http://grdagrd.com/uploads/3ac9ac4d9d69ef18785876438bb0a69a.jpg';
echo filesize($img);
```

**Error:**

> filesize(): stat failed for
>   http://grdagrd.com/uploads/3ac9ac4d9d69ef18785876438bb0a69a.jpg

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401131/easiest-way-to-grab-filesize-of-remote-file-in-php

Comment: `filesize` function only works for local files. To get the size from url, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635936/super-fast-getimagesize-in-php) may help.

Comment: It works. It even reports an error. You can't `filesize` stuff on servers that aren't yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filesize() works only with your local files. You have two choices:

1. Download the file and find the filesize
2. Use the following [get_header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) method:

function:

```
$file = get_headers("http://grdagrd.com/uploads/3ac9ac4d9d69ef18785876438bb0a69a.jpg", TRUE);
echo $file['Content-Length'];
```

Gives: `69322` as of yours

Moreover, you can also retrieve following details from get_headers:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Wed, 18 May 2016 09:55:10 GMT
    [Server] => Apache
    [Last-Modified] => Fri, 29 Apr 2016 16:00:34 GMT
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Content-Length] => 69322
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Type] => image/jpeg
)
```

There is also a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/f26300ffd7e50a92bc4d)

Answer (score 1):

May you are looking for this: [Easiest way to grab filesize of remote file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401131/easiest-way-to-grab-filesize-of-remote-file-in-php)

```
$img = "http://grdagrd.com/uploads/3ac9ac4d9d69ef18785876438bb0a69a.jpg";
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($img, TRUE));
echo $filesize = $head['content-length']; //69322
```

OR

```
echo strlen(file_get_contents($img)); //69322
```

Comment: Just wondering, why lowercase all the array keys? Does the `Content-Length` key differ in capitalisation according to server setups?

Comment: easy access, nothing else.